# How to fetch the authorization code from the browser using the application?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk

I have created a web application which uses the redirect uri as `http://localhost`. I have fetched the authorization code from the redirect uri and made use of it for my development. My doubt is when i am using an application which redirects me to the browser for allowing permission, how can i retrieve the authorization code from the browser using my application without copy-paste from the browser?

Comment: You can retrieve code from the url. What's the application in "when i am using an application"? Is it a installed application? or web application? Need more details about your scenario.

Comment: It is an installed application. How can i retrieve the auth. code from the url using 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'?

Comment: Hello Radcliff, did you get a solution to your problem? I am facing the same problem, plz share.

Answer (score -1):

As Google guide says:

> When you use this value, your application can then detect that the page has loaded, and can read the title of the HTML page to obtain the authorization code.

The tile of page will be like this:`Success code=AuthorizationCode`

So you can check the webpage, if the title contains this string, you'll get code.